# php in array error

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?PHP
$bannedIPs = array('127.0.0.1','72.189.218.85');

function ipban() 
{
    if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $bannedIPs)) 
    { 
        echo 'test';
    }   
}

ipban();

?>
```

The output of this script is:

> Warning: in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second
>   argument in C:\webserver\htdocs\test\array.php on line 93

Can someone tell me why? I don't get it

And yes `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is displaying 127.0.0.1

***UPDATE***

As suggested I tried this now but still get the same error

```
function ipban() {
    $bannedIPs = array('127.0.0.1','72.189.218.85');
    if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $bannedIPs)) { 
        echo 'test';
    }   
}
ipban();
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you have error reporting set to E_ALL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have run into a little problem with your variable scoping.

Any variables outside a function in PHP is not accessible inside. There are multiple ways to overcome this.

You could either declare `$bannedIPs` inside your function as such:

```
function ipban() {
    $bannedIPs = array('127.0.0.1','72.189.218.85');
    if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $bannedIPs)) { 
        echo 'test';
    }   
}
```

Tell your function to access `$bannedIPs` outside the function using the **`global`** keyword:

```
$bannedIPs = array('127.0.0.1','72.189.218.85');

function ipban() {
    global $bannedIPs;

    if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $bannedIPs)) { 
        echo 'test';
    }
}
```

Or, use the `$GLOBALS` super global:

```
$bannedIPs = array('127.0.0.1','72.189.218.85');

function ipban() {
    if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $GLOBALS['bannedIPs'])) { 
        echo 'test';
    }
}
```

I recommend you read the manual page on Variable scope:

[PHP: Variable Scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

---

**If it's still not working, you have another problem in your code. In which case, you might want to consider using a `var_dump()` to check what datatype is `$bannedIPs` before down voting us all.**

```
function ipban() {
    global $bannedIPs;

    var_dump($bannedIPs);
}
```

Comment: +1, especially for the downvote part. This is turning into a kindergarten thread.

Comment: Another way I found is by passing the variable into the function on call ipban($bannedIPs);

Comment: **@jasondavis:** Yes, but then you are making your function call more verbose for nothing. It's code smell.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `$bannedIPs` is out-of-scope inside the function. Read up on variables scope: http://php.net/variables.scope

```
$var = 'xyz';
function abc() {
    // $var does not exist here

    $foo = 'abc';
}

// $var exists here

// $foo does not exist here
```

RE: Update:

Moving the variable inside the function works, your code snippet executes fine. There's got to be something else in your code.

Comment: I tried moving the variable inside the function and it still has the same error

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you move $bannedIPs inside the function declaration? It's possible PHP thinks it's out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

You need to global $bannedIPs;

This works for me:

```
function ipban() {
    $bannedIPs = array('127.0.0.1','72.189.218.85');
    $ip = '127.0.0.1';
    if (in_array($ip, $bannedIPs)) { 
        echo 'test';
    }   
}
ipban();
```

So, you might want to see if that works, substitute in the IP address, and then finally replace it with the SERVER variable.

Comment: Which means that it is a problem with $_SERVER

Comment: And for some reason some idiots decided to mark down my answer ... really?

Comment: @Chacha102: Sorry, yes, because "try switching arguments" and "trim `$_SERVER`" is totally unfounded non-sense.

Comment: The entire problem was unfound nonsense. He even commented that for some reason it works now.

Comment: The original question was a perfectly valid scope problem, as the beginning of your answer says. The rest of your answer is bad advise. Feel free to edit it.